# How do you add a show desktop button to the dock (18.04)?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, appearance, ubuntu-dock

In 16.04 there was a button on the dock you could click that would minimize all open applications. Is there a similar button in 18.04?

It looked like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are threads explaining relatively complex ways to get this looking like it did in Unity, but what I did was go to the Ubuntu Software Center (app store) and just type in "Show Desktop Button" there is a little add on you can install which puts a little house icon on your top panel that you can click on to do exactly what you want :)

Comment: Not "exactly what you want", that extension adds the icon to the top bar, OP wants it in the dock.

Comment: Oh that's true! It is prettier on the doc, aesthetically...

Comment: This fix doesn't see to work in 20.04, head for the Gabriel Staples Option 1 solution in the duplicate linked at the top of the page